# Как правильно говорить: "означает" или "значит"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Как правильно говорить: "означает" или "значит"?

Comment: Смотря в каком контексте. Например: "Как много **значит** контекст для понимания смысла слова!". Место в рейтинге **означает** известность и богатство. [Эльмар Гусейнов. Чисто французское самоубийство. Покончил с собой один из самых известных кулинаров страны (2003) // «Известия», 2003.02.25]

Comment: Это разница вторых значений слов: является важным и свидетельствует.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, один или несколько примеров _предложений_, вызывающих затруднение. Выведение правильности или неправильности употребления слов из словарных обобщений чревато ошибками.

Comment: Это слова в некоторых контекстах пересекаются (совпадают) по смыслу

Answer (score 1):

Из морфемного состава слов можно определить их обобщенный смысл. Значить ― являться знаком. Означать ― ставить знак. Таки образом, в первом (основном)  значении глаголы совпадают по смыслу: **Что это значит (означает)?**

Но они различаются во втором значении:

Эта победа **много значила (была важной)** для команды.

Эта победа **означала  правильность** выбранной  стратегии игры (**свидетельствовала о правильности**).

Из словаря:

ЗНАЧИТЬ,  1.  **Иметь какой-л. смысл, означать** (о словах, знаках, жестах и т. п.). Кивок головы значит согласие. 2. **Иметь значение, быть важным, существенным;** играть роль. Его обещание значит много.

ОЗНАЧАТЬ,  1. **Иметь тот или иной смысл,** значение (о словах, знаках, жестах). Что означает ваше молчание? 2. **Свидетельствовать о чём-л., показывать что-л.** Выражение лица означало неудовольствие. // **Быть равнозначным, равносильным чему-л.** Посадка на лёд означала верную гибель.

Comment: На мой взгляд, смысл "иметь (то или иное по размеру) значение" слово "значит" приобретает только в сочетаниях, напр. в идиоме со словом "много". Слово "означать" в таких сочетаниях не употребляется, поэтому _различие самих двух слов_ проявляется преимущественно в их разной _разной сочетаемости_. Насчёт смысла "ставить знак": если исходить из практики употребления, а не из расчленения на части, то скорее "содержать знак, указывающий на что-то".

Comment: А сочетаемость как определяется: для каждого сочетания на слух или есть какое-то правило? Что касается морфемного состава, то меня заинтересовало значение приставки О.  Какой смысл она придает слову "означать" (исходя и ее собственного смысла)?